# Fastest way of determining most frequent factor in a grouped data frame in dplyr

Tags: r, performance, dplyr

I am trying to find the most frequent value *within a group* for several factor variables while summarizing a data frame in dplyr. I need a formula that does the following:

1. Find the most frequently used factor level among all factors for one variable in a group (so basically "max()" for counts of factor levels).
2. If there is a tie between several most-used-factor levels, pick any one of those factors-levels.
3. Return the factor-level name (not number of counts).

There are several formulas that work. However, those that I could think of are all slow. Those that are fast are not convenient to apply to several variables in a data frame at once. I was wondering if somebody knows a fast method that integrates nicely with dplyr.

I tried the following:

**generating sample data (50000 groups with 100 random letters)**

```
z <- data.frame(a = rep(1:50000,100), b = sample(LETTERS, 5000000, replace = TRUE))

str(z)
'data.frame':   5000000 obs. of  2 variables:
$ a: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ b: Factor w/ 26 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 6 4 14 12 3 19 17 19 15 20 ...
```

**"Clean"-but-slow approach 1**

```
 y <- z %>% 
    group_by(a) %>% 
    summarise(c = names(table(b))[which.max(table(b))])

user    system  elapsed 
26.772  2.011   29.568
```

**"Clean"-but-slow approach 2**

```
y <- z %>% 
    group_by(a) %>% 
    summarise(c = names(which(table(b) == max(table(b)))[1]))

user    system  elapsed 
29.329  2.029   32.361
```

**"Clean"-but-slow approach 3**

```
y <- z %>% 
    group_by(a) %>% 
    summarise(c = names(sort(table(b),decreasing = TRUE)[1]))

user    system  elapsed 
35.086  6.905   42.485
```

**"Messy"-but-fast approach**

```
y <- z %>% 
     group_by(a,b) %>% 
     summarise(counter = n()) %>% 
     group_by(a) %>% 
     filter(counter == max(counter))
y <- y[!duplicated(y$a),]
y <- y$counter <- NULL

user   system  elapsed 
7.061  0.330   7.664
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's another option with `dplyr`:

```
set.seed(123)
z <- data.frame(a = rep(1:50000,100), 
                b = sample(LETTERS, 5000000, replace = TRUE), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

a <- z %>% group_by(a, b) %>% summarise(c=n()) %>% filter(row_number(desc(c))==1) %>% .$b 
b <- z %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(c=names(which(table(b) == max(table(b)))[1])) %>% .$c
```

We make sure these are equivalent approaches:

```
> identical(a, b)
#[1] TRUE
```

**Update**

As per mentioned by @docendodiscimus, you could also do:

```
count(z, a, b) %>% slice(which.max(n))
```

---

Here are the results on the benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
mbm <- microbenchmark(
  steven = z %>% group_by(a, b) %>% summarise(c = n()) %>% filter(row_number(desc(c))==1),
  phil = z %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(c = names(which(table(b) == max(table(b)))[1])),
  docendo = count(z, a, b) %>% slice(which.max(n)),
  times = 10
)
```

[image]

```
#Unit: seconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#  steven  4.752168  4.789564  4.815986  4.813686  4.847964  4.875109    10  b 
#    phil 15.356051 15.378914 15.467534 15.458844 15.533385 15.606690    10   c
# docendo  4.586096  4.611401  4.669375  4.688420  4.702352  4.753583    10 a
```

Comment: Your code can be simplified to `count(z, a, b) %>% slice(which.max(n))`

Answer (score 6):

Why dplyr?

```
#dummy data
set.seed(123)
z <- data.frame(a = rep(1:50000,100),
                b = sample(LETTERS, 5000000, replace = TRUE))

#result
names(sort(table(z$b),decreasing = TRUE)[1])
# [1] "S"

#time it
system.time(
  names(sort(table(z$b),decreasing = TRUE)[1])
)

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.36    0.00    0.36
```

EDIT: multiple columns

```
#dummy data
set.seed(123)
z <- data.frame(a = rep(1:50000,100),
                b = sample(LETTERS, 5000000, replace = TRUE),
                c = sample(LETTERS, 5000000, replace = TRUE),
                d = sample(LETTERS, 5000000, replace = TRUE))

# check for multiple columns
sapply(c("b","c","d"), function(i)
  names(sort(table(z[,i]),decreasing = TRUE)[1])
  )
# b   c   d 
#"S" "N" "G" 

#time it
system.time(
  sapply(c("b","c","d"), function(i)
    names(sort(table(z[,i]),decreasing = TRUE)[1]))
  )
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.61    0.17    0.78
```

Comment: As I said, I need to do this for several variables that are connected not just one. If I wanted to do it this way, I would need to put an ID to every variable and merge them together in the end.

Comment: @Phil wrap it in `sapply` if you have multiple columns, see edit.

Comment: A nice. Still, currently it only gives me the top value per column. However, I would need the top value for each separate one of the 50000 groups in column "a". Is there a way to extend your function for that?

Answer (score 6):

`data.table` is still the fastest choice for this:

```
z <- data.frame(a = rep(1:50000,100), b = sample(LETTERS, 5000000, replace = TRUE))
```

Benchmarking:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

#dplyr
system.time({
  y <- z %>% 
    group_by(a) %>% 
    summarise(c = names(which(table(b) == max(table(b)))[1]))  
})
 user  system elapsed 
14.52    0.01   14.70 

#data.table
system.time(
  setDT(z)[, .N, by=b][order(N),][.N,]
)
 user  system elapsed 
 0.05    0.02    0.06 

#@zx8754 's way - base R
system.time(
  names(sort(table(z$b),decreasing = TRUE)[1])
)
   user  system elapsed 
   0.73    0.06    0.81
```

As it can be seen using data.table with this:

```
  setDT(z)[, .N, by=b][order(N),][.N,]
```

or

```
  #just to get the name
  setDT(z)[, .N, by=b][order(N),][.N, b]
```

seems to be the fastest

Update for all columns:

Using @zx8754 's data

```
set.seed(123)
z2 <- data.frame(a = rep(1:50000,100),
                b = sample(LETTERS, 5000000, replace = TRUE),
                c = sample(LETTERS, 5000000, replace = TRUE),
                d = sample(LETTERS, 5000000, replace = TRUE))
```

You could do:

```
#with data.table
system.time(
 sapply(c('b','c','d'), function(x) {
  data.table(x = z2[[x]])[, .N, by=x][order(N),][.N, x] 
 }))
 user  system elapsed 
 0.34    0.00    0.34 

#with base-R
system.time(
  sapply(c("b","c","d"), function(i)
    names(sort(table(z2[,i]),decreasing = TRUE)[1]))
)
 user  system elapsed 
 4.14    0.11    4.26
```

And just to confirm results are the same:

```
sapply(c('b','c','d'), function(x) {
  data.table(x = z2[[x]])[, .N, by=x][order(N),][.N, x] 
})
b c d 
S N G 

sapply(c("b","c","d"), function(i)
    names(sort(table(z2[,i]),decreasing = TRUE)[1]))
b   c   d 
"S" "N" "G"
```

Comment: I dont think your edit returns the correct result though

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm not familiar with data.table. Does that also return the value per group (so 50000 values for each group of values that has the same value in column "a"?). If so, could you tell me how I would access that?

Comment: It's preferable not to have the `>` and `+` starting lines, so others can more easily copy-paste and reproduce.

Comment: @Frank Yes you re right. Was too eager to go home I guess that I didn't bother. I ll fix

Comment: @Phil Actually, I don't get what you mean. Essentially we count the levels of the factor and return the max letter. how does this connect with column a? I don't get it. All the rest of the columns are aggregated. What would be in column a?

Comment: How about: `setDT(z)[, .N, by=.(a,b)][order(-N), .(b=b[1L]), keyby=a]`?

Comment: Thanks @Arun. Great answer. I think this is what the OP really wants. Don't you want to add it as an answer? (You should actually, this is your idea :) )

Comment: @Arun This indeed seems to be what OP wanted. Great answer. (and, once again, faster than `dplyr`)

Comment: LyzandeR, just posted, thanks. @StevenBeaupré, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Arun. Great answer!

Answer (score 4):

Following LyzandeR's suggestion, I'll add another answer:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(z)[, .N, by=.(a,b)][order(-N), .(b=b[1L]), keyby=a]
```

Comment: This looks very good. Is there a way to use sapply to apply that to several variables in one call? When I try `sapply(c("b","c"), function(i) {setDT(z)[, .N, by=.(a,i)][order(-N), .(i = i[1L]), keyby=a]}` I get an error.