# How to change the date from default to the right one based on other data?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this, only much bigger with additional columns, that are not of importance for this question.

```
  DAY MONTH YEAR NAME   SURNAME
1   1     1 2012 Luke Skywalker
2   3     4 2012 Luke Skywalker
3   3     4 2012 Luke Skywalker
4   1     8 2013  Han      Solo
5   5     8 2013  Han      Solo
6   5     8 2013  Han      Solo
7   1     1 2012  Ben      Solo
8   6     2 2011 Leia    Organa
```

The `DAY`,`MONTH`and `YEAR`signify the birthdate of the person. But because some dates were missing (but they had years), if there was no birthdate, the default was `DAY=1`and `YEAR=1`. There are more than one occurrence of the same name in the same year on the same date. Of course, some might have their birthday on `1.1.year`

What I want to do is, search for those that have the default value for their birthday and set it to the correct one.

What I did was: I made a sub data frame, that includes only those rows, where the `1.1.year` occurred only once for the same name in the same year (if it was in it more than once, we can presume that is his birth day) and where the person count (how many persons with the same name, surname and year are there in the whole df) is greater than 1. If it weren't, we would have only one row with the date and we couldn't say anything. (As is the case her with `Ben`). If there are only two occurrences, one with 1.1.year, one without, the one which isn't the default value (1.1) takes priority.

Now I planed to iterate through this new sub data frame, match every name surname and year and replace the date with the one, that is the most common for that name in that year, but I do not know how to do this efficiently. The data frame is big, so `for`loops are probably out of the question.

What I would like to get out is:

```
  DAY MONTH YEAR NAME   SURNAME
1   3     4 2012 Luke Skywalker
2   3     4 2012 Luke Skywalker
3   3     4 2012 Luke Skywalker
4   5     8 2013  Han      Solo
5   5     8 2013  Han      Solo
6   5     8 2013  Han      Solo
7   1     1 2012  Ben      Solo
8   6     2 2011 Leia    Organa
```

Comment: @ycw it was a typo, thank you

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766325/fastest-way-of-determining-most-frequent-factor-in-a-grouped-data-frame-in-dplyr) for some great answers on a similar problem.

Comment: What happened if there is a tie in terms of prevalence?

Comment: @ycw A tie between 1.1 and another one? The other one always has priority, as 1.1 is used as default.

Comment: I have posted my answer, but this answer assuming that there is no tie in the dataset.

Comment: If there are five records, two are October 10th, two are September 26th, One is January 1st, which one would you like to use to replace January 1st?

Comment: @ycw In that case, there are two possibilities. We either use the date from another column, in which there are test years and these years shouldn't overlap, meaning only one row for person per year. The other possibility is, we just choose at random, as long as it isn't 1.1.

Comment: I see. If that is the case, I think my solution is still valid.

Comment: @ycw Thank you. When I get to a computer, I will implement and test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`. Notice that this code does not deal with the situation when there is a tie in terms of prevalence in the datasets. It assumes that there is only one date that is most abundant in the records and select one record to replace records that are not dominant.

```
library(dplyr)
dt2 <- dt %>% 
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(NAME, SURNAME, DAY, MONTH, YEAR) %>%
  mutate(N = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(NAME, SURNAME) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(DAY, MONTH), funs(ifelse(N != max(N), NA, .))) %>%
  arrange(DAY, MONTH) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(DAY, MONTH), funs(ifelse(is.na(.), first(.), .))) %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  select(-N, -ID)
dt2
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   NAME, SURNAME [4]
    DAY MONTH  YEAR  NAME   SURNAME
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>     <chr>
1     3     4  2012  Luke Skywalker
2     3     4  2012  Luke Skywalker
3     3     4  2012  Luke Skywalker
4     5     8  2013   Han      Solo
5     5     8  2013   Han      Solo
6     5     8  2013   Han      Solo
7     1     1  2012   Ben      Solo
8     6     2  2011  Leia    Organa
```

#### DATA

```
dt <- read.table(text = "  DAY MONTH YEAR NAME   SURNAME
1   1     1 2012 Luke Skywalker
                 2   3     4 2012 Luke Skywalker
                 3   3     4 2012 Luke Skywalker
                 4   1     8 2013  Han      Solo
                 5   5     8 2013  Han      Solo
                 6   5     8 2013  Han      Solo
                 7   1     1 2012  Ben      Solo
                 8   6     2 2011 Leia    Organa",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```